# JPA merge() doesn't work as expected when resaving a modified object

Tags: java, persistence, jpa

This is my set up for the entity:

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "movies", schema = "public")
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private UUID movieId;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "actor", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Actors> actors = new HashSet<>();

    //Getters and setters
    }
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Table(name = "actors_movies", schema = "public")
public class ActorMovie {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ActorId id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("movieId")
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_movie_movie")
    private Movie movie;

    //Getters and setters below
}
```

I am able to successfully call `entityManager.merge()` when I add a new `Actor` to the list of movie. The following successfully persists the tables.

```java
Movie movie = getMovieById(id);
movie.setActors(new Actor());
entityManager.merge(movie);
```

Then I want to update the actor name so what I do is this. I am NOT able to update an already persisted/existing Actor:

```java
Movie movie = getMovieById(id);
movie.getActors().get(0).setName("New Name");
entityManager.merge(movie);
```

The above doesn't work, I can see the object being updated in debug mode but when `merge()` is called it doesn't update the database.

Where am I going wrong? I thought merge would update if already existing.

Answer (score 8):

The EntityManager. `merge()` operation is used to merge the changes made to a detached object into the persistence context. **merge does not directly update the object into the database,** it merges the changes into the persistence context (transaction).

When the `transaction` is committed, or if the persistence context is flushed, then the object will be updated in the database.

For you `merge` is not required, although it is frequently misused. To update an object you simply need to `read` it, then `change` its state through its `set` methods, then commit the `transaction`. The `EntityManager` will figure out everything that has been changed and update the database. `merge` is only required when you have a detached copy of a `persistence` object.

Just in your case you arent doing commit of transaction.

```
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

See the javadoc of the [EntityManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush--) interface's method [flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush--). You can use it to *synchronize the persistence context to the underlying database*.

If the [FlushModeType](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/FlushModeType.html) is set to `COMMIT` then underlying database is updated at the time of whole transaction commit. To resolve this you can [setFlushMode](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#setFlushMode-javax.persistence.FlushModeType-) to `AUTO (Default)` to flush each query. Or you can wrap some part of your code into `NESTED` [transaction](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html#propagation--) to flush only this part. Also you can periodically invoke the [flush()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#flush--) method inside current transaction:

```java
entityManager.flush();
entityManager.clear();
```